# Problem with the flds and fld instruction in arm

Tags: assembly, floating-point, arm, cross-compiling

I am writing an assembly program on Linux. I use this script to cross-compile the assembly to arm :

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -ggdb3 -nostdlib -o main -static main.S
```

Having a `main.S` like this :

```
.global _start
_start:
.text
    FLDS s31,=3.12E-16
```

However I get errors telling me that flds and  fld are not recognized.
I have searching for a bit but I cannot seem to find the source of the problem. I thought about using `arm-none-eabi-as` but I get other types of error like `garbage after flds` etc.

Comment: `flds` is `x87` instruction. Sounds like you want `vldr`.

Comment: That must me it. Thanks. What is weird is that on the official arm page, they have a doc mentioning flds. According to them it is compatible with all arm cpu ...

Comment: Do you have an url for that?

Comment: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0068/b/  ----here page 272 if you download the file ...

Comment: Ahha, my bad. Looks like it is valid. However gnu assembler does not seem to accept floating point constants which is puzzling. `flds s31,=3` assembles without error, but as far as I can tell produces wrong code as it just uses an integer not a float.

Comment: Yeah ... I noticed that VLDR and FLDS do the same thing when given integer, however it is still not working with floats .

Comment: `flds s31,=0x25B3DB13` might do what you want but it's tedious if you have to convert values by hand.

Comment: The thing is that I am making a compiler for a sub-language of Java and I want it to run on arm, so doing it by hand is not a "clean" option :-)

Comment: With VLDR I get the following error : ""Error: garbage following instruction -- `vldr.f32 S0,=1.1'" " I cannot seem to find the good way of using vldr ...

Comment: Well if you are making a compiler then that can do the conversion. Note that [gcc is doing the same](https://godbolt.org/z/K8s6M5os8).

Comment: Well, who am i to argue with gcc, I will do that. thank you for your help